# Custom Web part is not displaying to add in site Contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I created a new basic webpart, and deployed it into the SharePoint online app catalog. After that, I tried to add it to the site contents of one SharePoint site. But webpart is not visible under "From your organization" and "apps you can add". 
Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Sravan

Answer (score 0):

After testing your webpart in the workbench, you can deploy the webpart by following the next steps:

1. In the console window, go to the web part project directory created
2. In the console window, enter the following command to package the web part: gulp package-solution
3. Go to your appcatalog (usually at https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog
4. Drag and drop the package you just created
5. SharePoint displays a dialog and asks you to trust the packages, click on "DEPLOY"
6. Go to your site collection and click on the gear to select "Add an app"
7. In the search box type the name of your app and press enter
8. Select your app from the list and install it on the site
9. Go to a modern page, edit it and add your new webpart as needed

You cand find these steps and much more on the Microsoft tutorial for creating your first webpart (SPFx) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

Comment: Hi Gonzix, 
Thanks for your reply.
I followed the same steps as you mentioned, but in the 7th step, I can't find my app.

Comment: Could you share your app manifest?

Comment: same for me, i have deploy3ed webpart but not coming in apps to add in site. @Gonzix how you fixed it ?